# jboss7 on windows8-64bit. not run jboss

Tags: jboss

Sorry. my english skill is very poor..

OS windwos8
install jboss7.1.0 final 
and set JAVA_HOME , JBOSS_HOME
then run standalone.bat

console log

```
 Calling "C:\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: C:\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final

  JAVA: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java

  JAVA_OPTS: -XX:+TieredCompilation -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms128M -Xmx1
024M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.
server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.w
arning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.server.default
.config=standalone.xml

===============================================================================

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; sup
port was removed in 8.0
11:02:42,276 정보    [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
11:02:42,479 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
11:02:42,510 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" sta
rting
`
```

more don't proceed
what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According to Tomaz Cerar in this JBoss Community Forum thread:

https://community.jboss.org/message/808212?_sscc=t

JBoss AS7 does not support JDK 8. Try using WildFly, which is JBoss AS 8. This works with Java 8.

Comment: accepting the answer and voting it up would be a nice way to thank me.